# Why does this xhtml file display JS code but doesn't run the function

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Every time I try to run this xhtml file, it only displays the javascript file, it does not run the function. What am I doing wrong? Why the function does not run? I'm fairly new to JS and xhtml so any and all help is welcomed and appreciated. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--Submit form, Assignment 2-->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type = "text/javaScript" src = "mss58.js"></script>
<title> Submit Form Assignment </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>


<body>

<h1>Please Fill out the following Form</h1>
<form name ="SubmitForm" action = "mss58.js" onsubmit = "validate()" method="run">
Name: <input type ="text" name="firstname"><br />
Email address: <input type = "text" name="emailaddress"><br />
Password: <input type = "password" name = "pwd"><br />
Confirm Password: <input type = "password" name = "cpwd"><br />
Gender: <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "male">Male
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "female">Female<br />
        <br />
Comments: <br />
          <textarea rows ="10" cols = "50"></textarea><br />
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>           

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I got the form to submit correctly however my javascript file does not want to check. I'm guessing my if statements aren't work. Can someone give it a once over and tell me why, when I type in an invalid password, username, or email that no alerts pop up? I'm sure it's something obvious, I've just never used javascript before this class

```
function validate(){

var name = document.forms["SubmitForm"]["firstname"].value;
var email = document.forms["SubmitForm"]["emailaddress"].value;
var password = document.forms["SubmitForm"]["pwd"].value;
var cpass = document.forms["SubmitForm"]["cpwd"].value;

var arrloc = email.indexOf("@");
var perloc = email.lastIndexOf(".");

var alph = false;
var num = false;
var sym = false;


if(name == null || name == ""){
    alert("You must fill out the Name field");
    return false;
}


if(arrloc < 1 || perloc < arrloc + 2 || perloc + 2 >= email.length){
    alert("Email is not valid");
    return false;
}


for(var i = 0, i < password.length-1, i++){
    if(password.substring(i,i+1) == /[a-z]/){
        alph = true;
    }
    if(password.substring(i,i+1) == /[A-Z]/){
        alph = true;
    }
    if(password.substring(i,i+1) == /[0-9]/){
        num = true;
    }
    if(password.substring(i,i+1) == /[^\w+$]/){
        sym = true;
    }
}


if(alph == true && num == true && sym == true){
    return true;
}else{
    alert("Your password is invalid!");
    return false;
}


if(password == cpass){
    return true;
}else{
    alert("Your passwords do not match!");
    return false;
}


};

validate();
```

Comment: Because you tell it to. When the form is submitted, it redirects the browser to `mss58.js` because that's the `action` value. `run` is not a valid value for `method`, it will default to `get`. You should read first how forms work: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake and forgot to change that back but it currently says "post" there. I still can't get the function to run. I looked through the link but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The `type` attribute in the `<script>` tag is not necessary. But if you do want to write it, use `text/javascript` rather than `text/javaScript` (or any other capitalization variation).

Comment: @Roland: I believe it's necessary in XHTML.

Comment: @FelixKling ah - you're right. `type` is necessary in xhtml. Still, I always see the value spelled as text/javascript, all in lowercase.

Comment: @Roland: Yep, according to the specification, this value should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your javascript code into [`<script>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp) tag.

In order to run the defined function, you've to call it, for example, like this: `validate()`

Comment: My assignment is to call an external .js file so I can't add it directly into the file. should I be making a function call in the .js file or in the .html file? I don't know where to put it either. I can't seem to find any sort of decent help online.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
<form name ="SubmitForm" action = "mss58.js" onsubmit = "validate()" method="run">
```

to

```
<form name ="SubmitForm" action = "TARGET_PAGE.php" onsubmit = "return validate()" method="POST">
```

In your JavaScript validate function, it should return false when the data is incorrect and return true otherwise.

Comment: Ok I understand that. I'll give it a shot now. so the target_page is where I want the html file to go?  EDIT: I tried to change the mss58.js to something else but my browser keeps looking for a file and then it just opens the file.

Comment: Yea. TARGET_PAGE is where you want the entered data to be sent to. It could be a PHP, ASP or JSP files.

Comment: @user1701128: You want to prevent form submission if the the data is invalid. If you want to prevent submission, you have to return `false` from the `submit` event handler. You can write `onsubmit = "return validate();"` and either return `true` or `false` from `validate`, depending on the result.

Comment: @felixKling ok I got the form to work correctly (it now sends email as per my assignment) but now I think my .js file is not running correctly. I'll edit the original post with my code